# MVC with Decorator pattern

Tags: java, oop, model-view-controller, design-patterns, decorator

In a project im working on we hold a strict MVC structure. Im thinking of adding a decorator pattern to some of the modal windows (tiny popup windows) for those implementations where i whant some extra features.

So I basicly have the following:

```
SimpleModalWindowController.class
SimpleModalWindowModel.class
SimpleModalWindowView.class
```

**EDIT:**
Question: Is it possible to implement a decorator pattern upon this for new ModalWindows implemenations or should i go with inheritance? I will have many different windows and I would like to combine some of there functionalities in the future.

If I go by decorator pattern, what class whould be the abstract one?

***Would it be a class that combines all the above classes like SimpleModal.class to set them up as an abstract class or do I have more then one abstract class?***

Im obviously new to this pattern and only got average OOP-skills, so please have some patience.

Thanks for any help.

/Marthin

Comment: I don't think this qualifies as a decorator pattern. What you are trying to do is create inheritance hierarchy with specialization (Fancy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this qualifies as a decorator pattern. What you are trying to do is create inheritance hierarchy with specialization (Fancy).

**You don't need to implement Decorator.** The way you are implementing looks fine if that is addressing the design issue. You don't have to use a pattern in this case.

This is how a decorator would be implemented which you don't need. I am a C# guy, hence syntax may not be fully correct.

```
abstract class ModalWindowModel
{
  protected ModalWindowModel modalWindowModel; //This can be any class implementing/derived from ModalWindowModel
}

class SimpleModalWindowModel extends ModalWindowModel
{
 SimpleModalWindowModel(ModalWindowModel modalWindowModel)
 {
  this.modalWindowModel = modalWindowModel;
 }


 // your other code goes here
}

class FancyModalWindowModel extends ModalWindowModel
{
 FancyModalWindowModel(ModalWindowModel modalWindowModel)
 {
  this.modalWindowModel = modalWindowModel;
 }

 // your other code goes here
}

...
// Usage
ModalWindowModel simpleModalWindowModel = new SimpleModalWindowModel(null);
ModalWindowModel fancyModalWindowModel = new FancyModalWindowModel(simpleModalWindowModel);
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally i would implement it as a decorator. I generally prefer composition over inheritance for a [variety of reasons](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-1998/jw-11-techniques.html). Thereby i would do something like:

```
class ExtendedModalWindowModel {
   private ModalWindowModel model;
   public ExtendedModalWindowModel(ModalWindowModel model) {
      if (model == null) throw IllegalArgumentException("...");
      this.model = model;
   }

   // delegate common methods to the parent
   public int getSize() {
      // you could also put additional functionality here...
      return model.getSize();
   }

   // implement new functionality on the decorator
   public void doNewThings() {
      // ...
   }
}
```

Should your decorated classes implement tnterfaces, you should also implement them in the decorator (but still delegate to the decorated instance for their implementation-unless you want to extend or override the base functionality).

A good example of composition is the implementation of I/O in java: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html